# Python VS Code: Type hinting with multiple types

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, type-hinting, python-typing, pylance

I am using python type hinting in VS Code.

The `user_wildcard` variable can either be a `str="*.txt"`, or `bool=False`.

No problems here, python can run the code fine.
However, VS Code shows a "problem with my code" although there is no problem.

Is there are more "correct" way if type hinting so that I wouldn't get this problem in VS code?

[image: screenshot of VS code inline type hinting]

```py
import logging
class FileManager:
    def __init__(self):
        self.log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
        self.cwd = Path(__file__).parent

    def go_up(self):
        self.cwd = self.cwd.parent
        return self

    def get_cwd(self) -> Path:
        return self.cwd

    def cd(self, foldername: str):
        path = self.cwd / foldername
        if path.is_dir():
            self.cwd = path
            return self
        else:
            self.log.error(f"invalid {foldername=}")

    def find_file(self, filename: str, single_file: bool=False) -> list | Path:
        filepaths = self.cwd.glob(filename)
        if single_file:
            return next(filepaths)
        else:
            return [x for x in filepaths]

    def get_resource_file(self, use_wildcard: str | bool = False):
        self.go_up().cd("resources")
        if use_wildcard:
            return self.find_file(use_wildcard, single_file=True)
        else:
            raise NotImplementedError(f"{use_wildcard=}")
```

I read that support for Union is added from python>3.10, which eliminates the need for `from typing import Union`.

However, I have tried using Union but it shows the same problem as well.

[image: screenshot of using Union instead]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `find_file` method only expects its first argument `filename` to be a `str`. But inside `get_resource_file` the `use_wildcard` argument can be `str` **or** `bool`. So calling `self.find_file(use_wildcard)` is not type safe.

You can establish some sort of type guard before calling `find_file` to ensure that by that time `use_wildcard` is definitely a `str` (and cannot be a `bool` anymore). The simplest way is to check `if isinstance(use_wildcard, str)` instead of your current `if use_wildcard`.

Additionally, if you really only want to allow `use_wildcard` to be a `str` or the literal `False` (not any `bool`, i.e. not `True`), you can annotate that method using the [`typing.Literal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Literal) type as `str | Literal[False]`. In that case the check `if use_wildcard` is technically sufficient because anything *"truthy"* will necessarily be a (non-empty) `str`:

```py
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Any, Literal


class FileManager:
    def find_file(self, filename: str, single_file: bool = False) -> list[Any] | Path:
        ...

    def get_resource_file(self, use_wildcard: str | Literal[False] = False):
        ...
        if use_wildcard:
            return self.find_file(use_wildcard, single_file=True)
        else:
            raise NotImplementedError(f"{use_wildcard=}")
```

But even then I would recommend an explicit check. Though your semantics seems a bit off here anyway, but I assume the code is just not fully worked out yet.

Comment: Thanks @Daniil! Agreed, explicit check would be a better way. Thanks for the answer! It helped me to understand how type hint works better.